# error observed in 'cor.test' command for analyzing three variables of three data frame

Tags: r

I was trying to run

```
cor.test(
  amarraincor$jan, 
  akbarraincor$jan,
  anthonyraincor$jan
)
```

error showed up as:

> Error in match.arg(alternative) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector
>
> 4.
>   stop("'arg' must be NULL or a character vector")
>
> 3.
>   match.arg(alternative)
>
> 2.
>   cor.test.default(amarraincor$jan, akbarraincor$jan, anthonyraincor$jan)
>
> 1.
>   cor.test(amarraincor$jan, akbarraincor$jan, anthonyraincor$jan)

Comment: `cor.test` is for two variables only. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Three Data files are available. A same variable in these three files has to be analysed for Correlation.